FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest
I'm facing this issue since yesterday and it was working perfectly fine before. It's not resolving even though i've tried every possible way soo far. Please help me regarding this!
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node modules as chatGPT said. Also upgraded expo, installed expo cli, uninstalled/installed global expo as per guidelines. changed the network/wifi, followed every possible way as guided still getting the same error!!
ERROR:-------------------------from here----------------------------
Starting Metro Bundler
FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest: sha512-P6yRm04Cv/ak6XUOlpw/uTFrv3TYac3qeN5rfjcJlvYLWYv1CANdWsCBtbvW/tEPf98C98iLHzDzCu35DMXmvw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-P6yRm04Cv/ak6XUOlpw/uTFrv3TYac3qeN5rfjcJlvYLWYv1CANdWsCBtbvW/tEPf98C98iLHzDzCu35DMXmvw== but got sha512-/Ny5tVKTaRTbv6tIrzb3iWIUDC9GF8FEypuDv1o/b7r+qBkua8U+I3Rm/U9oeXwXfreIodXb0BUa+sqp4jf4Sg==. (29900 bytes)
FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest: sha512-P6yRm04Cv/ak6XUOlpw/uTFrv3TYac3qeN5rfjcJlvYLWYv1CANdWsCBtbvW/tEPf98C98iLHzDzCu35DMXmvw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-P6yRm04Cv/ak6XUOlpw/uTFrv3TYac3qeN5rfjcJlvYLWYv1CANdWsCBtbvW/tEPf98C98iLHzDzCu35DMXmvw== but got sha512-/Ny5tVKTaRTbv6tIrzb3iWIUDC9GF8FEypuDv1o/b7r+qBkua8U+I3Rm/U9oeXwXfreIodXb0BUa+sqp4jf4Sg==. (29900 bytes)
    at Pipeline.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:400:12)
    at Pipeline.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at Pipeline.emit (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\minipass-pipeline\node_modules\minipass\index.js:469:25)
    at Pipeline.emit (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\minipass-pipeline\index.js:106:18)
    at Pipeline.[_onError] (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\minipass-pipeline\index.js:84:12)
    at IntegrityStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\minipass-pipeline\index.js:74:44)
    at IntegrityStream.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at IntegrityStream.emit (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\minipass\src\index.ts:1087:19)
    at IntegrityStream.emit (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\ssri\lib\index.js:83:18)
    at IntegrityStream.#onEnd (C:\Users\Tejal\Projects\constro-plus-app\node_modules\ssri\lib\index.js:117:12)

------------------------------------to here-------------------------
This error I'm facing is in all the React Native projects, even those which are already present, and also for newly created ones! And this started to happen when I've finished uploading one of my projects to GitHub. I guess this was the reason or else it could be something else too. But it was still perfectly fine before.
Note:---- I think the code is not a problem here, because even a freshly built application is returning the exact same thing! And there's a 'minipass' named error that can be seen in the above-mentioned error. I've even tried installing it using 'npm install minipass' (chatGPT) still it's the same!

Please share the text of the error instead of a picture of the error. Also please share your code so that people can try to debug.

did the changes you've asked for.

did you try clearing cache? npm cache clear --force and then npm install.

yes I did, Actually thanks a lot for your responses! I really appreciate your presence that gave me a hope. It'll be good to hear to you too that I was successfully able to solve the issues by myself and one of my fellow contributor and you.

Good to hear! Please update your question body to share your solution or post an answer and accept it as the solution. This way, in the future, if a developer comes across this issue they might use your solution in a way.

Yes, I would definitely like to share my solution to this problem so that it can help someone.

Finally my projects are running! Actually the problem was NPAV, due to which my packages were getting corrupted (This happened when i uploaded my project(running/working) into GitHub and tried to make a copy of it for my workspace using SSH key. The project got downloaded but was corrupted which impacted into my overall setup!).
Solution:
steps: 1)To solve this, I excluded some of the folders(from NPAV).
I've also attached all the folder names that I've added in NPAV as folder exclusions in the image below.
2) Restart computer
3) run commands such as:
npm i,
npm cache clear --force,
npx expo start -c.
Note: I followed ChatGPT but I failed again and again until I followed the Antivirus/Firewall suggestions from ChatGPT itself and it worked. Thankyou.



hello i have the same error encountering right now  how did you fix this?

what did you do in your antivirus/firewall to make it work again?

Hey, Please check my another answer!

Solution: I'm providing the visualized solution below in the images respectively. After completing this steps "RESTART YOUR LAPTOP/DEVICE".And run commands such as: npm i, npm cache clear --force, npx expo start -c in your project's directory on terminal/command prompt.
For better understanding you can also read my previous answer given in the Answers section.





